# BCP command is not Working?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, odbc, bcp

We just migrated our SQL server to a cloud machine. Everything seems working but we are facing some issues with BCP command.

**a)** Whenever we run Job the job Process exit with Failure.`"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed"`. I find out that the `BCP.exe` is still running after doing his task.

**b)** BCP command import the data in table from file .It works correct but for % column it does not import the data completely it only load the data which is having % equals or greater than 1.
for others its giving:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]String data, right truncation.
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Well, can you provide the view/table definition which your trying to export? Can you provide the BCP command itself too?

Answer (score 0):

According to me check if the file which you are trying to BCP is not open in any other process. Also copy the file to new location and try agaian.